# OLS estimator proof of variance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, least-squares, econometrics

I am having trouble understanding the proof for variance portion below. Which rule did the author apply for variance? Does not look familiar to the standard variance formulas I have learnt. And what does the subscript x in this case mean, since for the said variance equation, there is a subscript of x only for one of the V[.] parts. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author used the [total variance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance?wprov=sfla1) stating that $\mathrm{var}(Z) = \mathrm{var}_X(E(Z|X))+E_X( \mathrm{var}(Z|X))$ with $Z=uX$. Then conditional variance and expectations are easy to compute.